# How to inject multiple classes that share the same interface in Laravel 4

Tags: php, dependency-injection, laravel, laravel-4, simplepie

Say I have an interface `CrawlerInterface` with implementation `PageCrawler` and `FeedCrawler`; if we happen to need both classes in a controller, how can that be achieved with constructor injection?

Previously we use a central `ServiceProvider` to register (i.e. `App::bind`) such classes, but in most cases we only have 1 implementation of an interface, so said problem hasn't occured to us yet.

PS: I also wonder if this problem suggests we should split the controller.

---

**Updates:**

Thanks for the comments and response, to explain, said interface has only one public method: `crawl($uri)`, and both page/feed crawler implements it as `given a resource identifier, return resource.`

---

**My follow up question:**

Say we are in a `calculator` scenario where Addition, Subtraction and Multiplication share the same interface `Operation`, which has only 1 public method `run`, at some point we will still encounter this problem right? How do we handle situation like these in general with `ServiceProvider`?

Comment: As some have pointed out, this may actually be a code smell (One that I've certainly run into myself!). Can you include *why* you chose to use an interface to implement? What differs between your 2 implementations? You may actually want to use concrete classes for dependencies as Antonio pointed out, or re-think the code architecture a little. Perhaps we can help with the underlying architecture which makes this an issue.

Comment: @fideloper thx, think I have a solution to the problem; but I am still a bit confused about how far can we take such approach, see my follow up questions.

Comment: I really think it's not a bad thing to have several implementations to an interface. However, if that's the case and you want to use many implementations at the same time, then there should be a reason based on their usage. For example I could have 2 caches in my application: one for the queries, the other one for my views. I then use "APCCache" for the queries and "FileCache" for the views, but as you can see, I don't care about the implementations, I just care that I have a "cache.queries" and "cache.views". It's the usage that's important.

Comment: @MatthieuNapoli i wonder how would one go about managing this with service provider...

Comment: I don't know about Laravel but usually DI containers offer the concept of "named services", i.e. a service not identified by a class/interface name but by an arbitrary name. I would request from the container the "cache.queries" entry, not the "Doctrine\Cache\CacheInterface" entry.

Comment: @MatthieuNapoli if it's not too much to ask, could you update your answer with an example with controller, i can't seem to figure out how to test or mock such named services...

Comment: @bitinn I've updated my answer with examples, and to be more clear of the difference between each solution. Let me know if it's clearer now.

Comment: @MatthieuNapoli thx it's much clearer, and i got mine working locally as well. i would like to wait a bit to see if there are better suggestion before giving out bounty :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**If each crawler exists for a different reason**, you can use arbitrary names for your instances, for example:

```
App::bind('crawler.allArticles', 'PageCrawler');
App::bind('crawler.latestArticles', 'FeedCrawler');
```

For the controller:

```
App::bind('CrawlerController', function($app) {
    return new CrawlerController(
        App::make('crawler.allArticles'),
        App::make('crawler.latestArticles')
    );
});
```

Your controller code would then use each crawler differently:

```
public function showLatestArticlesAction()
    $latestArticles = $this->latestArticlesCrawler->crawl();
    // ...
}

public function showAllArticlesAction()
    $allArticles = $this->allArticlesCrawler->crawl();
    // ...
}
```

---

**If you just have a list of crawlers where each is used for the same thing**, you probably want to do something like:

```
App::bind('crawlers', function($app) {
    return [
        App::make('PageCrawler'),
        App::make('FeedCrawler'),
    ];
});
```

In your controller, you'll get a list of "crawlers" by configuring it like so:

```
App::bind('CrawlerController', function($app) {
    return new CrawlerController(App::make('crawlers'));
});
```

Your controller code could be something like this:

```
public function showArticlesAction()
    $allArticles = array();
    foreach ($this->crawlers as $crawler) {
        $allArticles = array_merge($allArticles, $this->crawler->crawl());
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: say i use `CrawlerInterface.page` - is this like having an alias to PageCrawler, does it have advantage over injecting classes directly?

Comment: @bitinn in your example, yes it's the same and you shouldn't do that. The name should be about a different usage. For example in my app I have a "logger.main" (log errors) and a "logger.queries" (log DB queries). Then I choose which logger I want depending on what I want to log, not depending if I want to log to a file, to syslog, or to [FirePHP](http://www.firephp.org/).

Comment: So you should "name" your services when you have the same kind of object used for different things. However in your case, if you just want to get "all crawlers" to crawl all possible sources, then the 2nd solution (in my answer) is better.

Comment: seems like nobody came up with a better alternative, my first bounty is yours to take, thx for the help!

Answer (score 6):

Ok lets assume you have a `CrawlerController`

```
class CrawlerController extends BaseController 
{
    protected $crawler1;
    protected $crawler2;

    public function __construct(CrawlerInterface $c1, CrawlerInterface $c2)
    {
        $this->crawler1 = $c1;
        $this->crawler2 = $c2;
    }
}
```

an interface

```
interface CrawlerInterface{}
```

and concrete implementations of that intefrace called `PageCrawler` and `FeedCrawler`

```
class PageCrawler implements CrawlerInterface{}
class FeedCrawler implements CrawlerInterface{}
```

You would inject the dependencies by writing a service locator like

```
App::bind('CrawlerController', function($app) {
    $controller = new CrawlerController(
        new PageCrawler,
        new FeedCrawler
    );
    return $controller;
});
```

But as suggested by others you should rethink your logic, use it only if this kind
of architecture is unavoidable

Comment: Hmmm, I have never seen usa-case like this, should we really be returning the controller from `App::bind` closure? what implication does it have?

Comment: Since I never use this approach, I cannot say for sure if there are any implications, but on the first sight, you provide the dependencies manually instead of laravel doing it via reflection so there shouldn't be any problems

Answer (score 3):

I think that the interface won't help you in this case.

By doing:

```
App::bind('CrawlerInterface', '<implementation>');
```

You need to choose one:

```
App::bind('CrawlerInterface', 'PageCrawler');
```

or

```
App::bind('CrawlerInterface', 'FeedCrawler');
```

And then Laravel will inject it:

```
class CrawlerController {

    public function __construct(CrawlerInterface $crawler)
    {
    }

}
```

To have both you have 2 options

-Have 2 different interfaces

-Inject the implementations directly:

```
class CrawlerController {

    public function __construct(PageCrawler $pageCrawler, FeedCrawler $feedCrawler)
    {
    }

}
```

But I also think that, if you need something like this, you better rethink your logic.

Comment: what would have happen if we had 
`App::bind('CrawlerInterface', 'PageCrawler');
App::bind('CrawlerInterface', 'FeedCrawler');
` in the service container register method
and then the controller's constructor requires one input like this:

`class CrawlerController {

    public function __construct(CrawlerInterface $crawler)
    {
    }

}
`
 which implementation would be injected when `CrawlerController` is instantiated?

Comment: Only the last one, that is FeedCrawler, would probably be injected in that case, since that's the last one that was bound.